# cross domain tracking goals go to direct

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-ads-api

I have an issue with cross domain tracking for one of my clients.
When people go from one site to the the other they go to a different domain. There they finnish a servey and they convert on that site.

I have analytics set up and the data comes in from both websites, but the conversions are registered for direct en referral. I want to know what keywords in Adwords turned into the conversion.

can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up cross domain tracking as described in this [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342).

If you use Google Tag Manager, you can use the "Auto Link Domains" functionality that will take care of the details.

Otherwise, you'll essentially have to change the intialization of your tracking snippet from

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

to

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['your-second-domain.com'] );
```

Note that these solutions always require that you use the same Analytics property ID on both sites.